# Прокси-сервер на FreeBSD. Не могу открыть порт

Tags: прокси, порты, freebsd

Приветствую всех! У меня такая ситуация: никак не могу открыть порт 5000 для одной программы, которая настроена только на него - через этот порт программа должна подключиться к своему серверу в Интернете по протоколу tcp. Стоит прокси-сервер на FreeBSD 6.4, через который проходит весь траффик, порт 8080 открыт для всех рабочих станций, и по нему можно подключиться к серверу (подключение проверял командой в cmd: telnet 192.168.1.1 8080), где 192.168.1.1 - IP-адрес прокси-сервера. Мне, хотя бы, динамически прописать правило для открытия данного порта. Я это делаю так:

```
sudo ipfw add 11110 allow tcp from me to 192.168.1.126 5000sudo ipfw add 11111 allow tcp from 192.168.1.126 to me 5000sudo ipfw add 11112 allow tcp from me to <IP-адрес сервера программы> 5000sudo ipfw add 11113 allow tcp from <IP-адрес сервера программы> to me 5000
```

192.168.1.126 IP-адрес рабочей станции, на которой стоит программа. Хоть все эти правила и добавляются (проверял командой sudo ipfw list), но почему-то не работают: компьютер никак не может достучаться до "проксика" по порту 5000. Может я что-то не то и/или не так делаю? С FreeBSD я столкнулся не так давно, поэтому прошу понять.Заранее благодарю.

Comment: а эти правила перед запрещающими или после? кароч нужен вывод sudo ipfw list

Comment: Ссылка на скрны: https://docviewer.yandex.ru/?url=ya-disk%3A%2F%2F%2Fdisk%2Flist.rar&name=list.rar&c=523b27001cf1

Comment: Только созданы теперь ещё и правила, которые должны пропускать все компы (02300 и 02310) по 5000-ому порту (эти правила тоже не работают), а динамические я прописал для IP-шника другого компа для проверки (эти правила в самом конце, пробовал и в самое начало их засовывать). Ни так, ни так не работает. Даже уже не знаю что я делаю не так, и вообще то ли я делаю.